# Exporting release with Flex 4.6 "One or more errors were found when trying to build the release version."

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm getting an error with a Flex 4.6 project when trying to export a release version..... debug works fine, but when exporting a release version, I get the following error:

"One or more errors were found when trying to build the release version."

There are no errors in the "Problems" tab.....

I looked in the .log file of the Flexbuilder workspace and below is the error...

Does anyone have any clue as to how to go about fixing this?

```
!ENTRY com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 43 2013-12-11 17:59:03.223
!MESSAGE ExportReleaseVersionWizard: internal error occurred
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1029)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersionManager.doBuild(ExportReleaseVersionManager.java:359)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ui.ExportReleaseVersionWizard.doBuild(ExportReleaseVersionWizard.java:371)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ui.ExportReleaseVersionWizard.handlePageChanging(ExportReleaseVersionWizard.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$10.run(WizardDialog.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.firePageChanging(WizardDialog.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.doPageChanging(WizardDialog.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1218)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersionAction$1.run(ExportReleaseVersionAction.java:97)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersionAction.run(ExportReleaseVersionAction.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication.start(FlashBuilderApplication.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at java.io.File.setLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.putInfo(LocalFile.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferAttributes(FileStore.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copyFile(FileStore.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copy(FileStore.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.copy(LocalFile.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.CopyVisitor.copyContents(CopyVisitor.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.CopyVisitor.copy(CopyVisitor.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.CopyVisitor.visit(CopyVisitor.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.accept(UnifiedTree.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.copy(FileSystemResourceManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.copy(Resource.java:542)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.BuilderUtils.copyDependents(BuilderUtils.java:598)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.build(FlexProjectBuilder.java:425)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.ReleaseProjectBuilder.build(ReleaseProjectBuilder.java:219)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.ReleaseProjectBuilder.doReleaseBuild(ReleaseProjectBuilder.java:155)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersionManager$2.execute(ExportReleaseVersionManager.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at java.io.File.setLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.putInfo(LocalFile.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferAttributes(FileStore.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copyFile(FileStore.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copy(FileStore.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.copy(LocalFile.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.CopyVisitor.copyContents(CopyVisitor.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.CopyVisitor.copy(CopyVisitor.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.CopyVisitor.visit(CopyVisitor.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.accept(UnifiedTree.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.copy(FileSystemResourceManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.copy(Resource.java:542)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.BuilderUtils.copyDependents(BuilderUtils.java:598)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.build(FlexProjectBuilder.java:425)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.ReleaseProjectBuilder.build(ReleaseProjectBuilder.java:219)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.ReleaseProjectBuilder.doReleaseBuild(ReleaseProjectBuilder.java:155)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersionManager$2.execute(ExportReleaseVersionManager.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: Figured it out..... some of the assets I was including in the project were missing Date attributes... used File Date Touch for Windows to fix. download: http://date.bghot.com/download.php

Comment: Bizarre: Please post a formal answer to your own question.